# Making a request with Axios not working with certain request payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am using Axios and React and am running into a problem making a request to my API with a certain payload. When I make the request it doesn't look like it sends (Looking at Chrome network tools) and the promise never gets resolved or rejected. But if I change the 'phoneNumber' field to either be something else like 'phonenumber' it works and it also works if I remove any of the other fields.

I want to send this payload which doesn't work:

```
{
    firstName: 'firstname',
    lastName: 'lastname',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    phoneNumber: '1231231234',
    password: 'Testing123',
    confirmPassword: 'Testing123',
    acceptedTermsAndConditions: true,
    acceptedPrivacyPolicy: true,
}
```

This works:

```
{
    firstName: 'firstname',
    lastName: 'lastname',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    phonenumber: '1231231234', // Change number to lowercase
    password: 'Testing123',
    confirmPassword: 'Testing123',
    acceptedTermsAndConditions: true,
    acceptedPrivacyPolicy: true,
}
```

And this works:

```
{
    // firstName: 'firstname', - Remove any other field.
    lastName: 'lastname',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    phoneNumber: '1231231234',
    password: 'Testing123',
    confirmPassword: 'Testing123',
    acceptedTermsAndConditions: true,
    acceptedPrivacyPolicy: true,
}
```

My request code:

```
axios.post(this.url, {
    firstName: 'firstname',
    lastName: 'lastname',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    phoneNumber: '1231231234',
    password: 'Testing123',
    confirmPassword: 'Testing123',
    acceptedTermsAndConditions: true,
    acceptedPrivacyPolicy: true,
}, { 
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }, 
    withCredentials: true 
})
.then((res) => { // NEVER GETS CALLED
    resolve(res)
})
.catch((error) => { // NEVER GETS CALLED
    console.log(error)
    resolve(error.response)
})
```

**UPDATE:** I tried making the request using fetch instead of Axios and pretty much the same thing happens except with fetch it sends a request that remains pending but never gets resolved or rejected.

Comment: May not have anything to do with axios. Probably a server side issue. What does the Chrome network tab show as far as response from the server?

Comment: @codemonkey The server never gets any request logged. I added a update about what happens with fetch instead of Axios it sends the request but just remains pending.

Comment: So to be clear, the only thing you change is `phonenumber` -> `phoneNumber` while leaving everything else intact results in a call that never gets resolved and just stays in pending?

Comment: @codemonkey Yes that's correct when it is `phonenumber` it works when its `phoneNumber` it doesn't. Also the request works fine in postman.

Comment: Strange indeed. I guess the only way to troubleshoot from here is to actually reproduce it. Is it possible get your API endpoint to test posting to it?

Comment: @codemonkey I actually can't because it's company code and it's not live. Is there a direction you would go for testing that I can try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227429/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-robert-harbison).